# Can I build a link-to using the current route name?

Tags: ember.js

I have `foo` and `bar` routes, both routes have `foo.baz` and `bar.baz` subroutes.

Can I call `{{link-to}}` in such a way that it refers to the current route instead of having to use the fully qualified name in each case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a button with an handler that makes a transition:

```
actions:{
    bazClicked(){
        var moduleRouteName = this.get('routeName');
        this.transitionTo(moduleRouteName+'.baz', );
    },
        ...
```

Or (second option) pass path parameter with binding, and calculate it in your route.

```
{{#link-to (concat currentRouteName 'baz')}}text{{/link-to}}
```

In your component:

```
currentRouteName : Ember.computed(function(){
  return Ember.getOwner(this).lookup('service:-routing').get('currentRouteName');
})
```